# Add ookii dialogs into a Sharpdevelop VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, dll, sharpdevelop, folderbrowserdialog, ookii

When searching for an alternative to the FolderBrowserDialog, I found here answers mentionning the "ookii dialogs" librairies and I would like to use these dialogs in my project.  Being very new to VB.NET, I could not find precise instructions to successfully add that to my project.

I'm not even sure if it's possible since the ookii dialogs librairies I found are coded in C# and my application is coded in Visual Basic. Is it possible? Will the included .dll work anyway?

I use Sharpdevelop 4.4.2.  Here is what I tried so far :

1. 'Add reference' and browsed to the Ookii.Dialogs.dll
2. 'Add existing Item' and browsed to the Ookii.Dialogs.dll
3. 'Add reference/existing item' and browsed to the Ookii.Dialogs.xml

I Though I was good because now the auto suggest function of sharpdevelop let me pin to the properties and methods of the ookii librairies but I get a "Type not defined" error when trying to compile with

`Dim zzz As Ookii.Dialogs.VistaFolderBrowserDialog`

Am I just missing a proper 'imports' statement?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the okki dialogs work in vb.net. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf).

There is an exemple of `VistaFolderBrowserDialog`.

```
Imports Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim dlg As VistaFolderBrowserDialog = New VistaFolderBrowserDialog()
    
    'show the dialogbox for the user to choose the folder
    Dim folderResult As Object = dlg.ShowDialog

    'you can get the selected parth with this. Here I put it in a textbox. 
    TexBox1.Text = dlg.SelectedPath             


End Sub
```